# SQL : loop through same table with tree structure data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm on MySQL 8.0.24, and I have a tree structure table named `category`, it has 3 columns: `category_id`, `parent_id`, `image`.

| category_id | image | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 69 |  | 68 |
| 70 |  | 68 |
| 71 |  | 68 |
| 60 |  | 57 |
| 61 |  | 60 |
| 62 |  | 57 |
| 63 |  | 62 |
| 64 |  | 57 |
| 65 |  | 64 |
| 66 |  | 57 |
| 67 |  | 66 |
| 68 |  | 57 |
| 53 |  | 52 |
| 54 |  | 52 |
| 55 |  | 52 |
| 56 |  | 52 |
| 57 |  | 41 |
| 58 |  | 57 |
| 59 |  | 58 |
| 18 |  | 14 |
| 19 |  | 18 |
| 20 |  | 18 |
| 21 |  | 1 |
| 22 |  | 21 |
| 23 |  | 22 |
| 24 |  | 22 |
| 25 |  | 21 |
| 26 |  | 25 |
| 27 |  | 26 |
| 28 |  | 26 |

I want to use the resultset of `category_id` obtained from another query, loop thru each element in the array and try to see if a given `parent_id` can be matched.

For example, the resultset of `category_id` is {98, 60, 26}, and I want to find out if any of the 3 elements has a `parent_id` of 1.

Analysis:

98's `parent_id` is NULL,

60's `parent_id` is 57, 41

26's `parent_id` is 25, 21, 1

Therefore a hit is found.

I tried to understand and use the following SQL from [sql loop thru same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113118/sql-loop-through-same-table), with no luck...

```
with aa_category(category_id) as (select category_id from aa_category union all select nplus1.category_id from aa_category as nplus1, aa_category where aa_category.category_id = nplus1.parent_id) select category_id from aa_category;
```

How do I write this SQL?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support "arrays", so what do you mean *an array of `category_id`*?

Comment: Reworded. Thx alot!

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use recursive cte:

```
with recursive cte as (
select *, category_id originalCategory from category 
where category_id in (98, 60, 26)
union all
select c.*, cte.originalCategory from category c
join cte on cte.parent_id  = c.category_id 
)
select originalCategory,parent_id
from cte 
where parent_id = 1
```

| originalCategory | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 26 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0cd204a4298dd8f154e15e41a7227275)*

Comment: OP looks for existence only, so `SELECT EXISTS (..)` in outer query may be enough.

Comment: @Akina just demonstrating the method , he can adopt to his use case

Comment: Wow! You guys are really amazing! Gosh, I don't know how I can work this out by myself...